# What is the motivation for the unit circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, soft-question

I've been reviewing trigonometry, and when coming to the extension of the trigonometric functions from $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\theta$ is a real number, they utilise the unit circle. However, I have a few questions regarding the motivation behind this (I've tried searching online, though I haven't been able to find an answer to my question):

- Why choose a circle? If it was to satisfy the first quadrant and make it easy to define that part, couldn't you have the first quadrant be a quarter circle, and the rest some other shape (or do we like to preserve symmetry)?
- Why should we try and extend the trigonometric functions beyond the usual right angle triangle definition?

Comment: Your question is quite broad.  You are more likely to get a useful response if you trim it down a bit.

Comment: Try Googling the keywords "Triangular Function". Is it a trigonometric function? Exact;y. Now try Googling "Circular Function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometric functions are useful in triangles, but they are not limited to triangles. They can equally be called the circular functions.

Dealing with angles is about dealing with the rotation around a point. Why stop at a quarter turn? A complete turn makes much more sense, and of course we know that the function will continue to repeat itself as we make more and more turns.

We often teach the trigonometric equations to students as a property of a right-angled triangle, but this can lead to a conceptual block. Even allowing for triangles without a right angle, limiting trig functions to triangles means that students struggle to understand how the functions can be evaluated beyond a half turn.

Using the unit circle allows us to define $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ for all angles.

As for why we continue as a circle rather than as some other shape, it's not just about symmetry. You can derive the formulae for sums of angles from a purely triangle perspective: applying these formulae to give values of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ beyond a quarter turn yields the circle, too.

In response to your comment, I have expanded this last paragraph into a separate answer.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the derivation you mentioned at the end, how it leads to a circle?

Comment: @frog1944 I've added another answer that addresses this more fully.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, we like to preserve symmetry, but really this just ties in with your second question of why we want to extend it.
2. Because the circle, in its perfection, is crying out to us to use all four quadrants. More generally than the right triangle definition, we can consider $\sin(\theta)$ to be the $y$ component of the point on the unit circle at angle $\theta$ (counterclockwise) from the x-axis. And $\cos(\theta)$ is that same point's $x$ coordinate. Having rest of the unit circle is also very convenient practically speaking. For instance, it is often the case that we want to describe something oscillating back and forth, and it's often the case that a good description is something like $f(t) = \sin(t)$ where $t$ is time. So as time goes on, it goes back and forth. It's nice to have the trig functions defined for any number so we can compactly write down a description of a process that goes back and forth many times.
3. $\sin(5\pi/6)$ is the $y$ coordinate of the point of the unit circle at angle $5\pi/6$ from the $x$ axis in the clockwise rotation. I think that's $-1/2.$
4. It's just a convention. Since trig functions are widely-used across many fields, and they've been known about and taught in basic education for hundreds of years, it was likely (and fortunate) that the convention would eventually settle down and be uniform worldwide. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking).

Comment: Whoops, didn't see you trimmed the question down to points $1$ and $2.$ Was probably a good idea... just gonna put this comment here so people know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we continue as a circle rather than as some other shape is not just about symmetry. You can derive the formulae for sums of angles from a purely triangle perspective: applying these formulae to give values of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ beyond a quarter turn yields the circle, too.

Supose we have a unit circle only for the first quadrant, with $\cos$ and $\sin$ not yet defined for angles greater thean $\frac \pi 2$.

Consider angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ where $0 <\theta_1<\frac \pi 2$ and $0 <\theta_2<\frac \pi 2$.

Let $x_1=\cos \theta_1$, $y_1=\sin \theta_1$, $x_2=\cos \theta_2$, $y_2=\sin \theta_2$.

Since we have a circle for the first quadrant, we have $x_1^2+y_1^2=1$ and $x_2^2+y_2^2=1$.

The rules for $\cos$ and $\sin$ of compound angles can be derived without any need to depend on angles greater than $\frac \pi 2$.

$\cos (\theta_1+\theta_2)=\cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 - \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 = x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2$

$\sin (\theta_1+\theta_2)=\sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 + \cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 = x_1 y_2 + y_1 x_2$

Now let $\theta_3=\theta_1+\theta_2$ and choose $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ so that $\theta_3$ is in the second quadrant: ie $\frac \pi 2 < \theta_3 <\pi$.

Folowing the rules for $\cos$ and $\sin$ of compound angles, we have:

$x_3=\cos \theta_3=\cos (\theta_1+\theta_2)= x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2$

$y_3=\sin \theta_3=\sin (\theta_1+\theta_2)= x_1 y_2 + y_1 x_2$

Now consider $x_3^2+y_3^2=(x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2)^2+(x_1 y_2 + y_1 x_2)^2$

$x_3^2+y_3^2=x_1^2 x_2^2 + y_1^2 y_2^2-2x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 +x_1^2 y_2^2 + y_1^2 x_2^2+2 x_1 y_2 y_1 x_2$

$x_3^2+y_3^2 = x_1^2 x_2^2 + y_1^2 y_2^2 +x_1^2 y_2^2 + y_1^2 x_2^2$

$x_3^2+y_3^2 = x_1^2(x_2^2 + y_2^2)+ y_1^2 (y_2^2 + x_2^2)=x_1^2 + y_1^2=1$

So the coordinates in the second quadrant are points on the unit circle, too.

You can continue this to show that coordinates in the third and fourth quadrants are also on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what is there in the unit circle. Because its radius is 1 if I construct a right triangle with some radius as its hypotenuse you get that $\cos\theta$ is equal to its x-axis and $\sin\theta$ is equal to its y-axis. Now what does it gives us? First of all, we can give meaning for those functions with $\theta$ greater than $\frac{\pi}2$ and smaller than $2$. Secondly it has symmetry which we like to have because a lot of things can be understood from that about the behavior of a function. Thirdly, if we are on the unit circle and we know that $\sin\theta ,\cos\theta$ are the $(y,x)$ coordinates we can derive a lot of things. A simple example is $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. There are also few historical reasons that I'll not tell. If you want to know them, please comment and I'll search for a source of the historical reasons for you.